# makes pointer to integer without cast

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm having a bit of a problem with my code. The compiler is telling me that my code is making a pointer to an integer without a cast. Now I'm not familiar with what this means so maybe someone could point (pun very intended) me in the right direction. Also any general tips would be much appreciated!

The exact error is:

```
Homework3.c: In function ‘main’:
Homework3.c:32: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘add’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
Homework3.c:16: note: expected ‘int (*)[5]’ but argument is of type ‘int’
```

---

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #define INPUT_FILE_NAME "amounts.txt"
 #define PRODUCTS 5
 #define SALESPERSON 4
 #define AMOUNT 1449
 #define TOTALS 20

 void printOut(int [SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS], float [TOTALS]);
 float add(int [SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS], float, float [TOTALS] );

 int main(void){

    FILE *inputFile;
    int sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS];

    float data = 0.0;
    float totals[TOTALS];
    int count;

    inputFile = fopen(INPUT_FILE_NAME, "r");
    for ( count = 0; count < AMOUNT; count++){
        fscanf(inputFile, "%d", sales[SALESPERSON]);
        fscanf(inputFile, "%d", sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS]);
        fscanf(inputFile, "%f", &data);
        add(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS], data, totals[TOTALS]);
    }
    fclose(inputFile);

    printOut(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS], totals[TOTALS]);

    return 0;
 }

 void printOut(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS], totals[TOTALS]){

    int count2 = 0;
    int count3 = 0;
    int count4 = 0;

    for(count2 = 0; count2 < SALESPERSON; count2++){    
        for(count3 = 0; count3 < PRODUCTS; count3++){
            printf("Sales Person %d \t Product%d \t Total: %.2f\n", count2, count3, totals[count4]);
            ++count4;
        }
    }
    return ;
 }

 void add(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS], data, totals[TOTALS]){


    if(sales[SALESPERSON] == 1){
        if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 1){
            totals[0] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 2){
            totals[1] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 3){
            totals[2] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 4){
            totals[3] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 5){
            totals[4] += data;
        }
    }
    else if(sales[SALESPERSON] == 2){
        if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 1){
            totals[5] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 2){
            totals[6] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 3){
            totals[7] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 4){
            totals[8] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 5){
            totals[9] += data;
        }
    }
    else if(sales[SALESPERSON] == 3){
        if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 1){
            totals[10] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 2){
            totals[11] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 3){
            totals[12] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 4){
            totals[13] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 5){
            totals[14] += data;
        }
    }
    else if(sales[SALESPERSON] == 4){
        if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 1){
            totals[15] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 2){
            totals[16] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 3){
            totals[17] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 4){
            totals[18] += data;
        }
        else if(sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS] == 5){
            totals[19] += data;
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: I get more errors than that when I compile it.

Comment: There are a lot more errors. I don't want people doing out my entire code for me just needed help fixing that error haha

Comment: You've defined `add` to take the whole array as its first argument, but then you call it passing it only one element (which is also outside the bounds of the array--another problem).

Comment: Well now that I am sending the whole array into the function, that error clears up but I am now getting this error:

Homework3.c:41: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘[’ token Homework3.c:56: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘[’ token

Answer (score 2):

`sales[SALESPERSON][PRODUCTS]` returns the integer at position `PRODUCTS` of the array referenced at position `SALESPERSON` in `sales`.  You just need to pass `sales`:

```
add(sales, data, totals); //same thing with totals
```

You also don't give the length of the array for the function, so your definition should just be:

```
void add(int[][] sales, float data, float[] totals)
```

Comment: How would the prototype definitions look like then?

Comment: Also from doing that I am now getting this error
    Homework3.c:41: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘[’ token
    Homework3.c:56: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘[’ token

Comment: @TheMadHouse Prototypes should always match the function definition. The only difference should be the semicolon at the end.